# Drupal | remove default value of a select box constructed from Taxonomy

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a taxonomy attached with my content type. While creating node of that content type I see "- Choose one -" value in the drop down of taxonomy. I want to remove that and want to set default value to a specific term. What could be the preferable way of doing this? I also don't have much experience in Drupal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to resolve the issue now. Just added the following line in my form alter

```
unset($form['taxonomy'][$vocabulary_id]['#options']['']);
```